# Late binding of template function types C++

Tags: c++, maps, bind

I have a template function like this

```
template < typename T>
void Foo::func(T t)
{
}
```

And a caller function

```
void FOO::func2()
{
    std::function<void(const Foo&)> mp;
    mp = std::bind(&Foo::func);
    ...
    ..
    ..
    //Finally
    mp();
}
```

This gives a compilation error as I dont specify the type `mp = std::bind(&Foo::func);`. The problem is I don't know the type at that point, but only later do I get to know. Any ideas?

Comment: Member functions are bind to `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the code resulting in the failed compile.

1. When you `bind` a member function like this, you need to bind a reference or pointer to a valid object (`this`).
2. The `bind` requires a placeholder, basically asserting that an argument will be provided for that "place" when the functor is called.
3. When calling the `std::function`, you need to provide an appropriate argument as well.

So, in the end the code could look like;

```
mp = std::bind(&Foo::func<const Foo&>, this, std::placeholders::_1);
//                                           ^^^ the placeholder
//                                     ^^^^ an object
//                       ^^^ template argument

mp(*this);
// ^^^ the argument for the std::function
```

**Note: the "type" must match (or convert to) the type as specified in the `std::function`**.

```
std::function<void(const Foo&)> mp;
```

This is a function wrapper for a function accepting a `const Foo&` and returning a `void`. To support the "unknown" type scenario, a generic lambda is better suited to this purpose.

```
auto mp = [this](auto arg) { return this->func(arg); };
```

In order to support move only types (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<>`), the lambda can be modified as follows;

```
auto mp = [this](auto&& arg) {
  return this->func(std::forward<decltype(arg)>(arg));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Member functions must be bind to `this` plus you have to instantiate the template:

```
std::function<void(const FOO&)> mp;
mp = std::bind(&FOO::func<const FOO&>, this, std::placeholders::_1);
mp(*this);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b7aa8f9d72bfbc77)

Now if you don't know the type of the input parameter at the point of `bind`, one alternative is to use generic lambdas instead of `std::bind` and `std::function`:

```
void FOO::func2() {
  auto mp = [this](auto t) { func(t); };
  ...
  mp(/*call here with what ever*/);
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc50046307ae5c9c)